# 301 Redirect. Need help. Having a hard time

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to redirect URLs and can't get anything to work. Here is what I'm hoping to do:

Old URL:

http://www.example.com/asp.pl?_puri=astore.amazon.com%2Fthegi02-20%2Fdetail%2FB0001L0DFA%2Fassid

Needs to redirect to:

www.example.com

Anyone know of any way to do that?

Comment: There are various ways.  You can do it in apache in your .htaccess or using some backend code.  What technologies are you using?

Comment: I tried:

Redirect 301 /asp.pl?_puri=astore.amazon.com%2Fthegi02-20%2Fdetail%2FB0001L0DFA%2Fassid http://www.mainpage.com

in the .htaccess and it didn't work. I was told I need to use mod_rewrite, but i'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: If your question is about how to configure apache, you should ask it at serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

[`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) and all the other `Redirect*` directives do only work with the [URL path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax). So you cannot test the query.

But with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) you can:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_puri=astore.amazon.com&thegi02-20&detail&B0001L0DFA&assid$
RewriteRule ^asp\.pl$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```